# Merging tuples if they have one common element

Tags: python

Consider the following list:

```
tuple_list = [('c', 'e'), ('c', 'd'), ('a', 'b'), ('d', 'e')]
```

How can I achieve this?

```
new_tuple_list = [('c', 'e', 'd'), ('a', 'b')]
```

I have tried:

```
for tuple in tuple_list:
    for tup in tuple_list:
        if tuple[0] == tup[0]:
            new_tup = (tuple[0],tuple[1],tup[1])
            new_tuple_list.append(new_tup)
```

But it only works if I have the elements of the tuple in a certain order which means it will result in this instead:

```
new_tuple_list = [('c', 'e', 'd'), ('a', 'b'), ('d', 'e')]
```

Comment: your merge strategy is not clear

Comment: I want to merge every tuple that has an element in common: `('c', 'e') with ('c', 'd') ` because 'c' in common which gonna give us `('c', 'e', 'd') ` and then merge that with `('d', 'e') ` because 'd' and 'e' in common which will result in `('c', 'e', 'd')`

Comment: Can you build from the following example which basically answers a VERY similar question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9118312/finding-tuples-with-a-common-element ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You could consider the tuples as edges in a graph and your goal as finding [connected components](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Connected_component_(graph_theory)) within the graph. Then you could simply loop over vertices (items in tuples) and for each vertex you haven't visited yet execute DFS to generate a component:

```
from collections import defaultdict

def dfs(adj_list, visited, vertex, result, key):
    visited.add(vertex)
    result[key].append(vertex)
    for neighbor in adj_list[vertex]:
        if neighbor not in visited:
            dfs(adj_list, visited, neighbor, result, key)

edges = [('c', 'e'), ('c', 'd'), ('a', 'b'), ('d', 'e')]

adj_list = defaultdict(list)
for x, y in edges:
    adj_list[x].append(y)
    adj_list[y].append(x)

result = defaultdict(list)
visited = set()
for vertex in adj_list:
    if vertex not in visited:
        dfs(adj_list, visited, vertex, result, vertex)

print(result.values())
```

Output:

```
[['a', 'b'], ['c', 'e', 'd']]
```

Note that in above both the components and elements within a component are in random order.

Answer (score 6):

If you don't need duplicate values (the ability to preserve `['a', 'a', 'b']`, for example), this is a simple and fast way to do what you want via sets:

```
iset = set([frozenset(s) for s in tuple_list])  # Convert to a set of sets
result = []
while(iset):                  # While there are sets left to process:
    nset = set(iset.pop())      # Pop a new set
    check = len(iset)           # Does iset contain more sets
    while check:                # Until no more sets to check:
        check = False
        for s in iset.copy():       # For each other set:
            if nset.intersection(s):  # if they intersect:
                check = True            # Must recheck previous sets
                iset.remove(s)          # Remove it from remaining sets
                nset.update(s)          # Add it to the current set
    result.append(tuple(nset))  # Convert back to a list of tuples
```

gives

```
[('c', 'e', 'd'), ('a', 'b')]
```

Answer (score 1):

This has a bad performance because list-contains checks are `O(n)` but it's quite short:

```
result = []

for tup in tuple_list:
    for idx, already in enumerate(result):
        # check if any items are equal
        if any(item in already for item in tup):
            # tuples are immutable so we need to set the result item directly
            result[idx] = already + tuple(item for item in tup if item not in already)
            break
    else:
        # else in for-loops are executed only if the loop wasn't terminated by break
        result.append(tup)
```

This has the nice side-effect that the order is kept:

```
>>> result
[('c', 'e', 'd'), ('a', 'b')]
```

Answer (score 1):

I had that problem with sets so I'm contributing my solution to this. It combines sets with one of more common element as long as possible.

My example data:

```
data = [['A','B','C'],['B','C','D'],['D'],['X'],['X','Y'],['Y','Z'],['M','N','O'],['M','N','O'],['O','A']]
data = list(map(set,data))
```

My code to solve the problem:

```
oldlen = len(data)+1
while len(data)<oldlen:
    oldlen = len(data)
    for i in range(len(data)):
        for j in range(i+1,len(data)):
                if len(data[i]&data[j]):
                    data[i] = data[i]|data[j]
                    data[j] = set()
    data = [data[i] for i in range(len(data)) if data[i]!= set()]
```

Result:

```
[{'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'M', 'N', 'O'}, {'X', 'Y', 'Z'}]
```

Answer (score 1):

The task becomes trivial with [NetworkX](https://networkx.github.io/), library for graphs manipulation. Similar to [this answer by @niemmi](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42036326/7851470) you'd need to find the [connected components](https://networkx.org/documentation/latest/reference/algorithms/generated/networkx.algorithms.components.connected_components.html):

```
import networkx as nx

tuple_list = [('c', 'e'), ('c', 'd'), ('a', 'b'), ('d', 'e')]
graph = nx.Graph(tuple_list)
result = list(nx.connected_components(graph))
print(result)
# [{'e', 'c', 'd'}, {'b', 'a'}]
```

To get the result as a list of tuples:

```
result = list(map(tuple, nx.connected_components(G)))
print(result)
# [('d', 'e', 'c'), ('a', 'b')]
```

Answer (score 0):

Use sets. You are checking for overlap and accumulation of (initially small) sets, and Python has a data type for that:

```
#!python3

#tuple_list = [('c', 'e'), ('c', 'd'), ('a', 'b'), ('d', 'e')]
tuple_list = [(1,2), (3,4), (5,), (1,3,5), (3,'a'),
        (9,8), (7,6), (5,4), (9,'b'), (9,7,4),
        ('c', 'e'), ('e', 'f'), ('d', 'e'), ('d', 'f'),
        ('a', 'b'),
        ]
set_list = []

print("Tuple list:", tuple_list)
for t in tuple_list:
    #print("Set list:", set_list)
    tset = set(t)
    matched = []
    for s in set_list:
        if tset & s:
            s |= tset
            matched.append(s)

    if not matched:
        #print("No matches. New set: ", tset)
        set_list.append(tset)

    elif len(matched) > 1:
        #print("Multiple Matches: ", matched)
        for i,iset in enumerate(matched):
            if not iset:
                continue
            for jset in matched[i+1:]:
                if iset & jset:
                    iset |= jset
                    jset.clear()

set_list = [s for s in set_list if s]
print('\n'.join([str(s) for s in set_list]))
```

Answer (score 0):

I bumped into this problem when resolving coreferences, I need to merge sets in a list of sets that have common elements:

```py
import copy

def merge(list_of_sets):
    # init states
    list_of_sets = copy.deepcopy(list_of_sets)
    result = []
    indices = find_fist_overlapping_sets(list_of_sets)
    while indices:
        # Keep other sets
        result = [
            s
            for idx, s in enumerate(list_of_sets)
            if idx not in indices
        ]
        # Append merged set
        result.append(
            list_of_sets[indices[0]].union(list_of_sets[indices[1]])
        )
        # Update states
        list_of_sets = result
        indices = find_fist_overlapping_sets(list_of_sets)
    return list_of_sets

def find_fist_overlapping_sets(list_of_sets):
    for i, i_set in enumerate(list_of_sets):
        for j, j_set in enumerate(list_of_sets[i+1:]):
            if i_set.intersection(j_set):
                return i, i+j+1
```

Comment: @MSeifert's code is more elegant, but for `list_of_sets = [{1, 2}, {2, 3}, {4}, {5, 6}, {4, 5}, {3, 7}]`, the output would be `[{1, 2, 3, 7}, {4, 5}, {5, 6}]`, which is a little bit confusing, while this method gives `[{4, 5, 6}, {1, 2, 3, 7}]`.  Maybe good for different use cases.