# Merging sets with common elements?

Tags: python, set

I would like to merge sets with common elements. For example

```
input = set([frozenset([1,2,3,4]), frozenset([3,4,5,6,7,8]),  frozenset([1,1000]),
             frozenset([100, 200]), frozenset([100, 300, 400])])
```

Result:

```
set([frozenset([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8, 1000]), frozenset([100,200,300,400])])
```

What would be an efficient way to achieve this?

Comment: @AustinHastings This operation is much faster and easier with sets. I've posted a proper strategy.

Comment: @TemporalWolf the solution involves sets, and it would be the same for lists, tuples, etc. You want to merge a bunch of collections together? Built sets.

Comment: The connected components approach is much more efficient than a brute-force all-pairs `set.union`/`set.intersection` algorithm.

Comment: Here is my Python code snippet. https://colab.research.google.com/drive/138dsnfmM2mbM7ZJv8fcMKw6bafNyBni1#scrollTo=f3t5qe28Ddd0

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here are what I tried. Firstly, I did something simple but wrong

```
result = set()
while input:                                                                   
    r = set(input.pop())
    for rr in input.copy():
        if rr & r:                                                  
            input.remove(rr)
            r.update(rr)  
    result.add(frozenset(r))
```

The problem with this code is that the merging may not be complete, depending on the order of the `input.pop()`. Suppose `input={frozenset([0, 1]), frozenset([2,3]), frozenset([1,2])}` and the three elements get popped out and looped over in this assignment order, then `results={frozenset([0,1,2]), frozenset([2,3])}`.

Then I implemented the answer [in this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42036188/merging-tuples-if-they-have-one-common-element). It first builds an adjacency list of a new graph, each node corresponds to one `frozenset` element of the `input`. An edge exists between two nodes (`frozenset`s) if they share common elements. Then depth first graph traversal is used to find the connected components of this new graph.

```
result, visited = set(), set()
components = collections.defaultdict(list)
adj_list = collections.defaultdict(list)

def dft(node, key):
    visited.add(node)
    components[key].append(node)
    for neighbor in adj_list[node]:
        if neighbor not in visited:
            dft(neighbor, key)

for r1, r2 in itertools.combinations_with_replacement(input, 2):
    if r1 & r2:
        adj_list[r1].append(r2)
        adj_list[r2].append(r1)
for node in adj_list:
    if node not in visited:
        dft(node, node)

for node, neighbors in components.iteritems():
    result.add(node.union(*neighbors))
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the built-in [set.union()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#set.union) -> only include results where the length of [set.intersection()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#set.intersection) is greater than 0.

---

This answer explains at a high level how to implement what you want. If you want a specific solution, you'll have to show your efforts to solve the problem first.

Comment: I didn't vote you down.

Comment: @nos That doesn't change my policy of only providing equivalent effort -> I don't mind helping you figure out how to do it, but you'll have to show an effort to solve it.