# Java 8 - Merge All Subsets Containing Common Elements

Tags: java, merge, java-8, set

Starting with a set of sets "groups":

```
Set<Set<String>> groups = new HashSet<>();
```

I want to create a new list of sets by merging all subsets with common elements:

i.e. Starting with the sets below:

```
A = {a, b, c}
B = {c, d, e, f}
C = {f, g, h, i, j}
D = {k, l, m}
E = {m, n, o}
F = {p, q, r}
```

The final result would be:

```
Set 1 = {a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h, i, j}
Set 2 = {k, l, m, n, o}
Set 3 = {p, q, r}
```

Any advice on how to accomplish this would be appreciated.

EDIT: In case of uneven sets it would perform the same. So if it were a method, it pseudo would look like this:

```
public void doStuff(){

  Set<Set<String>> groups = {{a,b,c}, {c,d,e,f}, {m, n, o}}

  Set<Set<String>> newGroups = mergeSubsets(groups);

  System.out.println(newGroups);
}

public Set<Set<String>> mergeSubsets(Set<Set<String>> groups){

     //some operations

}
```

Console out:

```
   New Groups: {{a,b,c,d,e,f}, {m, n, o}}
```

Comment: What did you try to achieve the same? Whats the logic for the grouping of Set1,2,3

Comment: Any two arbitrary subsets consisting of a non null intersection should be merged. I believe it lends itself to some sort of recursive solution but I'm having a tough time figuring this one out.

Comment: solve it on a sheet of paper - there is clearly an algorithm behind it. then write the Java code

Comment: or use the search, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42211947/merging-sets-with-common-elements) is already a Python based solution

Comment: How does your resulting set have two `c`s?

Comment: @CoffeeIsProgramming My other question still remains unanswered, what is the logic of merging the Sets. Why not merge all of them into one? Or why not 1st and 3rd in your later example?

Comment: Why not merge them all into one? Because that is not the requirement. Why not the first and third in my latter example? Because it is not the requirement. 

The intersection of {a,b,c} and {m,n,o} is empty.

I want to create a new list of sets by merging all subsets with "common" elements

Comment: Okay, I get it better and how about {{a,b,c}, {c,d,e,f}, {e, n, o}}, what would be the output for this?

Comment: No worries, output would be: {{a,b,c,d,e,f,n,o}} 
It would chain recursively because sets 1 and 2 have the element c in common and sets 2 and 3 have the element 'e' in common.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the imperative way based on @NiksVij solution. Obviously the solution of @NiksVij is not correct and this answer aims to fix this and extend a bit more:

```
public class MergeSet {

    public static void main(String... args) {
        List<Set<String>> list = new ArrayList<>();
        String[] A = {"a", "c", "e", "g"};
        String[] B = {"b", "d", "f", "h"};
        String[] C = {"c", "e", "f"};
        String[] D = {"b"};

        list.add(new HashSet<>(Arrays.asList(A)));
        list.add(new HashSet<>(Arrays.asList(C)));
        list.add(new HashSet<>(Arrays.asList(B)));
        list.add(new HashSet<>(Arrays.asList(D)));

        List<Set<String>> newGroups = merge(list);
        System.out.println(newGroups);

    }

    @SuppressWarnings("empty-statement")
    private static <T> List<Set<T>> merge(List<Set<T>> list) {
        if (list == null || list.isEmpty()) {
            return list;
        }
        List<Set<T>> merged = new ArrayList<>();
        do {
            merged.add(list.get(0));
            list.remove(0);

            while (mergeStep(merged.get(merged.size() - 1), list));
        } while (!list.isEmpty());
        return merged;
    }

    private static <T> boolean mergeStep(Set<T> setToCheck, List<Set<T>> remainingList) {
        boolean atLeastOnceMerged = false;
        Iterator<Set<T>> iterator = remainingList.iterator();
        while (iterator.hasNext()) {
            Set<T> elements = iterator.next();
            boolean doMerge = !Collections.disjoint(elements, setToCheck);
            if (doMerge) {
                atLeastOnceMerged |= doMerge;
                setToCheck.addAll(elements);
                iterator.remove();
            }
        }
        return atLeastOnceMerged;
    }
```

Answer (score 6):

You can just implement the algorithm as you describe it in your problem statement -- find intersecting sets and merge them until there is nothing to merge.  Standard library has a method [`Collections.disjoint`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#disjoint-java.util.Collection-java.util.Collection-) that helps by determining if two collections have any elements in common:

```
// this implementation sacrifices efficiency for clarity
public Set<Set<String>> mergeSubsets(Set<Set<String>> groups) {
    Set<Set<String>> result = new HashSet<>();
    for (Set<String> set : groups) {
        // try to find a set in result that intersects this set
        // if one is found, merge the two.  otherwise, add this set to result
        result.stream()
                .filter(x -> !Collections.disjoint(x, set))
                .findAny()
                .ifPresentOrElse(   // this method was added in java 9
                        x -> x.addAll(set),
                        () -> result.add(new HashSet<>(set))
                );
    }

    // if nothing got merged we are done; otherwise, recurse and try again
    return result.size() == groups.size() ? result : mergeSubsets(result);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.util.*;

public class MergeSet {
    public static void main(String... args) {
        List<Set<String>> groups = new ArrayList<>();
        String[] A = {"a", "b", "c"};
        String[] B = {"c", "d", "e", "f"};
        String[] C = {"f", "g", "h", "i", "j"};
        String[] D = {"k", "l", "m"};
        String[] E = {"m", "n", "o"};
        String[] F = {"p", "q", "r"};

        groups.add(new HashSet<>(Arrays.asList(A)));
        groups.add(new HashSet<>(Arrays.asList(B)));
        groups.add(new HashSet<>(Arrays.asList(C)));
        groups.add(new HashSet<>(Arrays.asList(D)));
        groups.add(new HashSet<>(Arrays.asList(E)));
        groups.add(new HashSet<>(Arrays.asList(F)));

        Set<Set<String>> newGroups = mergeSubsets(groups);
        System.out.println(newGroups);

    }

    private static Set<Set<String>> mergeSubsets(List<Set<String>> groups) {
        List<Set<String>> newGroups = new ArrayList<>();
        Set<String> init = groups.get(0);
        groups.remove(0);
        newGroups.add(init);
        while (!groups.isEmpty()) {
            removeMergedElementFromGroupAndUpdateNewGroup(newGroups.get(newGroups.size() - 1), groups);
            if(!groups.isEmpty()) {
                init = groups.get(0);
                groups.remove(0);
                newGroups.add(init);
            }
        }
        return new HashSet<>(newGroups);
    }

    private static void removeMergedElementFromGroupAndUpdateNewGroup(Set<String> master2, List<Set<String>> masterList) {
        Iterator<Set<String>> iterator = masterList.iterator();
        while (iterator.hasNext()) {
            Set<String> strings = iterator.next();
            boolean merge = strings.stream().anyMatch(string -> master2.contains(string));
            if (merge) {
                master2.addAll(strings);
                iterator.remove();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Hope this helps instead of `Set<Set<String>> groups` I have used `List<Set<String>> groups` for the ease of using lists if you have a constraint of using Set only , you can generate List from Set(say yourSet) by passing it into the constructor of Lists implementation , for eg.

```
groups = new ArrayList<>(yourSet);
```

Comment: This does not work for `String[] A = {"a", "c", "e", "g"};
        String[] B = {"b", "d", "f", "h"};
        String[] C = {"c", "e", "f"};
        String[] D = {"b"};`

Comment: Logic is fine . It was missing an empty check. Have added that check. Thanks for pointing out the miss