# compare similarity of multiple texts using python

Tags: python, text, nlp, analysis

So i have about 300-500 text articles that i would like to compare the similarity of and figure which are related / duplicates some articles might be addressing the same topics but not identical. so to tackle this i started experimenting with spaCy and the similarity function .. now the problem is similarity only compares two documents at a time and I think i would need to loop every single text and to compare it to the other one which is a very slow and memory consuming process is there a way around this ?

Comment: "now the problem is similarity only compares two documents at a time". Why exactly is this a problem?  Do you have any justification that this task should be less than N^2 time complexity?

Comment: Yes sorry should have clarified this part; is there a way to reduce the N^2 time ?

Comment: There may be, but first you will need to strictly define what you are trying to do with this data.  If simply talking about finding similar articles, it seems inherent that every potential pair of articles would be a valid candidate to check, hence N^2. That is unless you implement some kind of approximation method whereby only a non-dense subset of pairs will be considered, but the quality of result will not be the same.  Especially the fact that you seek to find duplicates suggests that you are interested in pair similarity here

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how you are going to go about comparing similarities between texts, but let's say that you are going to compare each one to another using Jaccard or cosine similarities.

Then, you could use the all-pairs similarity search proposed in [this paper](https://static.googleusercontent.com/media/research.google.com/en//pubs/archive/32781.pdf) which has an implementation [here](https://github.com/ekzhu/SetSimilaritySearch). This algorithm is extremely fast, especially for such a small data size.

The all-pairs search returns two documents and their similarity, so if you want to find a "family" of similar documents, then you will further need to apply a graph traversal like DFS. [A stack overflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42036326) on `python` tuples uses adjacency lists and provides O^(n+m) time complexity.

[Here's](https://github.com/wonhyukchoi/redditjokes) an example where you could use the all-pairs algorithm that tries to find reposts in the reddit jokes subreddit.